# Error "Invalid tag" on renderToStaticMarkup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am new to reactjs..

I am trying to render the component (jsx) using renderToStaticMarkup but I am getting the below error:

**Error:**

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: <html data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-re....
```

**server.js (snippet)**

```
var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
            React.createElement(
            ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Component(props))
        ),
        script({dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html:
            'var APP_PROP = ' + safeStringify(props) + ';'
        }}),

      script({src: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.min.js'}),
      script({src: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.min.js'}),
      script({src: '/bundle.js'})

    )
        response.send(html)
    }
```

component.jsx

```
return(
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <div>
            <ul>{values}</ul>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) accepts either a **single** string that can be an HTML tag (div, li, custom html tag) or a `ReactClass` of your component.

So you can do the following

```
  // Declaring the component (a stateless component in this case)
  const MyComponent = ({ onClickHndlr, children }) => (
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <ul>{children}</ul>
          <button onClick={onClickHndlr}>Click Me!</button>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );

  // Declaring my click function handler that I'll 
  // be passing it as a prop to the React.createElement method.
  const onClickHndlr = () => {}

  ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
    React.createElement(
      MyComponent, 
      { 
        onClickHndlr: onClickHndlr 
      }, 
      [ <li>first children</li>, <li>second children</li> ]
    )
  );
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gcsz4e1/)

Please, notice that i'm passing in an argument of type `ReactClass` (the stateless component `MyComponent`) to the `renderToStaticMarkup` method.

You could as well use some JSX as argument, as you would normally in a component's `render()` method, like so:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
  <MyComponent onClickHndlr={onClickHndlr}>
    <li>first children</li>
    <li>second children</li>
  </MyComponent>
);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw2vko3s/)

> Just keep in mind that JSX is (roughly) doing this conversion:
>
> - If the tag name is a string that maps to an HTML element, use the component class for that HTML element.
> - If the tag name is not an HTML element, assume it is a local variable name that points to a custom component class.
> - Attributes are converted into an object and passed as the second parameter.
> - Child elements are passed as the remaining parameters.

Extracted from [React JS Tutorial and Guide to the Gotchas](https://zapier.com/engineering/react-js-tutorial-guide-gotchas/).